# c# How doI check a user input string to see if it is in numeric form (so I can then parse it to an integer)?

Tags: c#, input

How can I check a user input string to see if it is in numeric form (so I can then parse it to an integer) in c#?

Answer (score 1):

Use Int.TryParse().
It returns a boolean that indicates if the string is a valid integer, and the parsed value as an out param.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

```
     int number;
     bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
     if (result)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);         
     }
```